# Redux forms render fields based on prop values

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-form

I am creating a form using redux-forms (v7.4.2). I am trying to conditionally render a field based on PROP values. To be clear, I am NOT trying to conditionally render a field based on the inpit of another field in the form. I want redux-forms to look at a prop value and render a field one-way or another base on the value of that props.

I tried the code below but it just shows both fields. The props are present (I can see them using react dev tools). Basically, what I'm aiming to do here is to look and see if a prop exisits. If the length of that array is > 0 then a user is edititng the form and I want to disable this field. Otherwise, if length === 0 then its a new record and the field is required.

```
{this.props.facilityCompliance.length === 0 ?
                        <Field
                            label="Facility Name"
                            name="facilityName"
                            placeholder="Facility Name"
                            component={renderInputField}
                            type="text"
                            validate={required}
                        />
                        :
                        <Field
                            label="Facility Name"
                            name="facilityName"
                            placeholder="Facility Name"
                            component={renderInputField}
                            type="text"
                            disabled={true}
                        />}
```

Comment: This should work, can you post the entire code into a codesandbox for further debugging ? on a side note instead of having 2 fields like this I would just put the condition in the `disabled` and in the `validate` properties so you don't have to repeat the Field code

Comment: Thanks @stilllife - I just moved the logic to the disabled property and all is well.